# How to include picture in banking style with exactly position

Tags: moderncv

I would like to include a picture in banking style moderncv pacakge. I just want to locate it  in right hand side from title. But.. I can do this with a simple

```
\includegraphics[scale=1]{picture}
```

because the picture is above or below title. I´ve thought in TikZ to create a node where I can put the picture but I´m not sure about this solution. Anyone know how could get it?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

With `moderncv` v2.0, the command to be patched is no more `\maketitle` but `\makehead` and the length to be changed is now `\makeheaddetailswidth`, so the correct patches for this version are

```
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\hfil}
  {\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\\[2.5em]}
  {\hfil\raisebox{-.7cm}{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}\\[2.5em]}
  {}
  {}
```

---

### Original answer (works with older versions of `moderncv`)

Add the following lines in your preamble

```
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\hfil}
  {\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
  {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\\[2.5em]}
  {\hfil\raisebox{-.7cm}{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}\\[2.5em]}
  {}
  {}
```

and, to insert the picture, use

```
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\hfil}
  {\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
  {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\\[2.5em]}
  {\hfil\raisebox{-.7cm}{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}\\[2.5em]}
  {}
  {}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}

\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: +1 I nearly commented in mine that one _ought_ to insert the image into a redefined maketitle but since a CV is presumably a one-off document I decided to go for simpler if less logically pure markup:-)

Comment: That´s exactly what I want. Thank you. But I don´t understand how I can reduce the space between title and picture, I mean, horizontal lenght between them.

Comment: @FJSJ In the last `\patchcmd` remove `\hfil`. If it is not enough, substitute it with `\hspace*{-15pt}` and adjust `-15pt` to your needs. You can also adjust `-.7cm` in `\raisebox` to adjust the vertical placement.

Comment: To complete the patch, add `\setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}` before the `\framebox`, this respects any given border width. Thanks for the patch anyways :)

Answer (score 10):

Put the picture in any convenient place in the source and use

```
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(20,30){\includegraphics[scale=1]{picture}}
\end{picture}
```

The `(0,0)` means that the construct takes up no space and will over (or under) print any surrounding text, then adjust the coordinates `(20,30)` to put it where you like, default units `pt` but you can change `\unitlength` so that you can use cm or in or whatever.

Comment: I´ve tried to do this with \put command but It didn´t work. Now with your tip is perfect. This option has advantage in cover letter (if you don´t want to show picture in it). Thank you again!

Comment: +1 because you're the best and your answers are always useful :-)