# ModernCV Banking photo title

Tags: moderncv

I added a photo in ModernCV Title using the command below. The results are in example 1. I would like to have it in a way that the both the photo and title are centered in the title as one bloc as in example 2.

**Code**

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstylebanking}{%
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  \oldmakecvtitle%
  {\raggedleft\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{picture}\par}%
}%
}{%
}
\makeatother
```

**Example 1**
[image]

**Example 2**
[image]

Comment: No it's not. I want both the title and photo on the same line. Thanks ;)

Comment: what about this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154383/how-to-include-picture-in-banking-style-with-exactly-position ?

Comment: but this is not I want :D I saw this before. I want them together centered in half. Actually what he did in this post can be also achieved using `\begin{textblock}{0}(11.4,0.5)
 \includegraphics[scale=0.07]{photo}
\end{textblock}`

Comment: If you notice from my photos examples that even the title is shifted to the left to make space for photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy workaround. I used `\hskip` to shift `\makecvtitle` and placed the photo using `\begin{textblock}` as follows

```
\hskip -3.5cm {\makecvtitle}

\begin{textblock}{0}(10.5,1)
  \includegraphics[]{picture}\par
\end{textblock}
```

I believe you can use `\being{minipage}` in `\begin{document}` to achieve the same results but this is working just perfect for me.

**Result**
[image]

**Update**
You have to add `\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch `\maketitle` - used by the `banking` style in [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) to create the title.

The default width of the title in `banking` is `.8\textwidth`, leaving `.2\textwidth` "to play with. The patch below inserts an image to the right of the title:

```
\patchcmd{\maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\\[2.5em]}% <search>
  {\hfill\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,height=50pt]{example-image}\\[2.5em]}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

You may have to fiddle with the vertical positioning through `\raisebox`:

[image]

Comment: but for the size of the photo am using it also goes on new line :/

Comment: maybe I just flush to left and use `textblock` to locate it where I want.

Comment: @Odin: I've used the `width` and `height` options to rescale the image to fit. Anything wider than `.2\textwidth` will make it go to the following line.

Comment: Exactly. My idea if possible to have them as one block to center in page. For now I will flush title left to see if someone comes up with solution

Comment: You may also be interested in using `\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[..]{...}}` which will raise the box `<len>` from it's current placement (downward if `<len>` is negative) but won't influence the other components (due to `[0pt][0pt]`).