# Moderncv banking: Photo on the right side of title

Tags: moderncv

Right now I'm trying to setup my CV in banking style. I want the photo to be on the right side of the title.

[image]

In the following link the user had the same problem and he got help.
[ModernCV Banking photo title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201144/moderncv-banking-photo-title/340413#340413)

Solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201259/119348

I tried to implement the code but without succcess. Can you provide a MWE for me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Writing a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) can be a lot of effort, why don't you provide a "not quite working" [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) here (emphasising why it's not perfect if it's not obvious) and then it's easier for people to spot what is wrong and offer a fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstylebanking}{%
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  {\centering\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}\par\vspace{10pt}}%
  \oldmakecvtitle%
}%
}{%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Here is a MWE with the picture on top.

According to the solution from the link above, this should do the trick:

> Easy workaround. I used \hskip to shift \makecvtitle and placed the
>   photo using
>
> ```
> \begin{textblock} as follows
>
> \hskip -3.5cm {\makecvtitle}
>
> \begin{textblock}{0}(10.5,1)
>   \includegraphics[]{picture}\par
> \end{textblock}
> ```

Comment: You should add this MWE to your question by editting it rather than posting it as an answer, probably without the `\makeatletter` stuff which isn't necessary as it is a hack to solve a different problem.  The answer you link to suggests replacing `\makecvtitle` with the fragment `\hskip ... \end{textblock}`.