# Include photo in moderncv-banking (does not work)

Tags: moderncv

I tried to use this instructions:
[How to include picture in banking style with exactly position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154383/how-to-include-picture-in-banking-style-with-exactly-position?newreg=a0f4dff227b44d0888e9439a02e01e62)

They somehow doesn't work anymore, maybe because the actual `moderncv` version
is a little bit different, I think.

Can maybe someone help me? It would be really nice.

if i use the code from the link: MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} 
\patchcmd{\makehead}
{\hfil}
{\hspace*{0.15\textwidth}}
{}
{}
\patchcmd{\makehead}
{\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
{\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.67\textwidth}}
{}
{}
\patchcmd{\makehead}
{\\[2.5em]}
{\hfil\raisebox{-.7cm}{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}\\[2.5em]}
{}
{}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name
```

It compiles correctly, but there is no picture in the pdf.
Here is the log file: https://pastebin.com/5Q5wTZZR

Comment: We would need more information in order to address your problem. For example, a minimal example that replicates your issue (and possibly your `.log` when you compile).

Comment: right, now i added more informations

Comment: From the posted `.log` file it seems like you have local installation/version of [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv). The version on CTAN is `v2.0.0` (2015/07/28) while you have `v1.2.0` (2012/10/31). There has been many changes to `moderncv` that would break previous versions/usage. Specifically, there is a `moderncv.cls` in your working folder, and your compilation uses that, rather than wherever your MiKTeX is installed.

Comment: omg, ok i was so confused. I didn't knew MiKteX already has the latest moderncv+templates, i instead used one from latex.org forums thinking it's the latest one. Thank you very much

Comment: Is everything working as expected now?

Answer (score 1):

You have a local copy of `moderncv.cls` in your working folder. The only way for one to pick this up is from the `.log` file:

[image]

Notice how `moderncv.cls` is listed as-is, while other files included are listed using their full path. Local versions/files within the working folder will be posted like this, rather than with their full path.

Remove this local version so your document can use the default installed version. There has been a number of major changes to [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) that will break earlier code.